# How to implement my own oauth solution? How would I do it in python?

Tags: python, session, oauth, oauth-2.0, tornado

I've read through multiple articles online, but I can't seem to find any way to properly implement my own oauth solution in python.

I'm using the tornado framework for python and I ended up converting [python-oauth2](https://github.com/wndhydrnt/python-oauth2)'s tornado solution to their most modern API with the hopes of understanding what makes up oauth2 work. I even made a contribution to the github. The biggest problem is that even after reading a large portion of the original oauth documentation, I don't understand everything. It leaves me confused when trying to make a simple oauth log-in.

A place I've looked are:

http://www.slideshare.net/leahculver/implementing-oauth -- Good slides, but since the speaker explained a lot in person of it I'm lost on some generic parts.

If you want to skip the reading, allow me to summarize:

1. I need a simple, yet well thought out explanation of how O-Auth 2.0 works, and how I could implement my own O-Auth 2.0.
2. I would like to know a good way to use python to do it.

Comment: Are you building an OAuth provider or building a client?  If client just use [oauthlib](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib) and follow the documentation there.  If writing a provider you got _a lot_ of reading to go, good luck.

Comment: I am trying to create a provider.

Comment: Then you need to consider which framework you want to integrate your provider with, which means you need to understand how the user system works, how to store all the temporary/access credentials, consumers, and scope management, or you have to write all of those things.  It's not simple, there is no simple explanation, you have to do _a lot_ of research, especially on the security side of things.  For reference, it took me about 4-5 weeks of reading (specs and guides) and research before I wrote my first line of code for an OAuth provider.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot more sense to why it's been so difficult for me to understand this. I'll do a lot more research on this.